# How to use quarkus-rest-client-reactive-jackson in Keycloak SPI

Tags: rest, jackson, keycloak, quarkus, keycloak-spi

I'm building a Keycloak 23.0.3 custom provider (SPI) that adds claims to the access tokens generated by Keycloak. These claims should be obtained by performing external REST API calls. For the REST client I would like to use `quarkus-rest-client-reactive-jackson` because it allows creating REST clients with interfaces, which is very fast and easy.
The problem is that when I try to create the client I get the error:

```
Uncaught server error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/microprofile/rest/client/RestClientBuilder
```

I have done some research and it seems that the dependency `quarkus-rest-client-reactive-jackson` is not present in the Keycloak server (that is a Quarkus)... so I have to include it.

The `dependencies` part of my `pom.xml` is the following:

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-core</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <version>23.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-server-spi</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <version>23.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-server-spi-private</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <version>23.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-services</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <version>23.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-model-jpa</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <version>23.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.30</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.json.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.json.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.json-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.quarkus/quarkus-rest-client-reactive-jackson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client-reactive-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Focus on the last part, the `quarkus-rest-client-reactive-jackson` dependency.

The REST client I'm using (as an interface) is this one:

```java
@Path("/my-path")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public interface TokenRestInterface{
    @POST
    @Path("/token")
    TokenDtoResponse getToken(@HeaderParam("User-Id") Integer userId, @FormParam("client_id") String clientId, @FormParam("client_secret") String clientSecret, @FormParam("grant_type") String grantType);
}
```

The part of the code where I try to create the REST client is the follwing:

```java
TokenRestInterface tokenRestInterface = null;
try {
    tokenRestInterface = RestClientBuilder.newBuilder().baseUrl(new URL("http://localhost:8080/")).build(TokenRestInterface.class);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
TokenDtoResponse tokenDtoResponse = keycloakRestInterface.getToken(userId, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, "client_credentials");
return tokenDtoResponse.getAccess_token();
```

The error I get when the previous code gets executed is:
`2023-12-19 11:47:43,443 ERROR [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (executor-thread-1) Uncaught server error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/microprofile/rest/client/RestClientBuilder`.

Based on this, I suppose the exception is thrown in the line: `RestClientBuilder.newBuilder()...`.

Note that I included both jars (my provider and the dependency jar) in the `providers` folder of Keycloak.

[image: providers folder of my Keycloak server]

(Note that `metacontratas-keycloak-provider` is the name of my project, my custom Keycloak provider)

Could you please explain to me how to solve this error? This is, do you know how to add correctly the dependency I'm using into the Keycloak service?
Thanks!

Comment: `quarkus-rest-client-reactive-jackson` won't really work as a provided dependency.

Comment: Neither does it as a compile dependency.

Comment: Why don't you use the HttpClient from the JDK ? See https://www.baeldung.com/java-httpclient-post

Comment: @Serkan Actually, until I cannot make ``quarkus-rest-client-reactive-jackson`` work I'm using the HttpClient class. The problem is basically the amount of code you need to build a request using HttpClient compared to the amount of code you need to build them using the library. Using HttpClient, the code is also more difficult to maintain. Note that we are building large calls to microservices, with various query parameters and headers.

Answer (score 0):

As I wasn't able to make `quarkus-rest-client-reactive-jackson` work, my solution was to use `resteasy-client` instead. This is, add the following to the `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
  <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
  <version>6.2.6.Final</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Add the following *jars* to the `keycloak/providers` folder:

[image: Keycloak providers folder]

And create the REST client in your provider with the following:

```java
UriBuilder fullPath = UriBuilder.fromPath("http://localhost:8080/your-path");
ResteasyClient client = (ResteasyClient) ClientBuilder.newClient();
ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(fullPath);
this.tokenRestInterface = target.proxy(TokenRestInterface.class);
```

Note that, to this day, the version of the Keycloak server must be < 23.0.0 because of [this](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/25589) issue.

Hope it helps!